# jszip folder not accessible after file creation

Tags: javascript, angular, web, zip, jszip

I am using jszip for my angular application.
I have unzipped the zip files. So there are files present
with folders such as
images, texts

so the unzipped files list look like this

```
images/image1.jpg
texts/my_text_file.txt
```

I tried to create a new file

```
this.codeUnZipped.file('folder2/name.txt','my content here');
```

It is properly added to the list of files

```
images/image1.jpg
texts/my_text_file.txt
folder2/name.txt
```

I zipped this file and on checking the content of the zip file, it seems that the folder2 is broken and not accessible anymore.

This issue occurs not all the time. Is there any reason for this to happen?